# Angular4: Patternfly Secondary nav not working after bootstrapping the app inside keycloak.init()

Tags: angular, angular-cli, keycloak, keycloak-services, patternfly

This the first time I am configuring my Angular4 application with keycloak authentication. Here I am using patternfly for nav menu. Initially my menu was 
[image: working as expected as you can see the screenshot]

For this I had bootstrapped my app like :
main.ts

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {KeycloakService} from './keycloak.service';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But when I had implemented the Keycloak, changed my main.ts:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {KeycloakService} from './keycloak.service';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';


KeycloakService.init()
  .then(() => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  })
  .catch(() => window.location.reload());
```

[image: the nav manu stopped toggling on hover as be seen on the screenshot]

My HTML for the menu is :

```html
<div class="nav-pf-vertical
            nav-pf-vertical-with-sub-menus
            nav-pf-vertical-collapsible-menus
            collapsed"
            >
  <ul class="list-group"  style="border-top:1px solid #efefef">
    <li class="list-group-item"  routerLinkActive="active">
      <a routerLink="orders">
        <span class="fa fa-folder-open"
          tooltip="{{'administration_myOrders_label' | translate}}"
          placement="right"
          container="body"></span>
        <span class="list-group-item-value">{{'administration_myOrders_label' | translate}}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item secondary-nav-item-pf"  data-target="#ipsum-secondary">
      <a>
        <span class="fa fa-list"
          tooltip="{{'administration_myQueues_label' | translate}}"
          placement="right"
          container="body"></span>
        <span class="list-group-item-value">{{'administration_myQueues_label' | translate}}</span>
      </a>
      <div id="ipsum-secondary" class="nav-pf-secondary-nav">
        <div class="nav-item-pf-header">
          <a class="secondary-collapse-toggle-pf" data-toggle="collapse-secondary-nav"></a>
          <span>{{'administration_myQueues_label' | translate}}</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a>
              <span class="list-group-item-value">Boston MA - Safety(workorder)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a>
              <span class="list-group-item-value">Boston MA - Safety(workorder)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a>
              <span class="list-group-item-value">Boston MA - Safety(workorder)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here I am using angular-cli in this app. And the Angular 4.3.5 Can somebody please give a solution.
Note : I have tried linking the patternfly css to index.html and remove it from angular-cli.json from webpacking; still could not make it work

Comment: Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: No, there is no error.

Comment: I have tried to use APP_INITIALIZER. still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by setting a timeout to: $().setupVerticalNavigation(true)

```
setTimeout(function() { $().setupVerticalNavigation(true) }, 2000);
```

inside script.js $(document).ready(function(){})